# HSQLDB-Database set URL/DB relative to project

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB the first time. Now i have to set the URL. 
`jdbc:hsqldb:file:MyPath`

Now my problem. I dont want to set the path of the url/DB "strong". I want to make it relative to the project/compiled project. 
For example: If my object is at the desktop, the file should be in a folder called "bla". How can i do it?

Thanks for the help.
Chris

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are on windows.
You can try something like this.

`jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:.\\path\\to\\file\\file` (you can ommit the .\\)

I did not try this with HSQLDB, but this is how you generally specify relative paths in Java for a Windows machine; on Unix systems you have to use / instead of \\.

If you want to get a relative path, not related to your project, then you can also use `System.getProperty("user.home")` and take the path to the file from there.

Comment: When using relative paths, these paths will be taken relative to the directory in which the shell command to start the Java Virtual Machine was executed (source : http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html)